# I want a slider button in flutter

Tags: flutter, layout

**UPDATE**

By using **Aminul Islam's** answer, I was able to successfully implement forward swiping. Now, I would like to enable reverse swiping as well, so that users can swipe in both directions. Can you provide guidance on how to achieve this?

This is my desired output.

[image]

I have tried almost every package but couldn't achieve this output. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

This SlideToContinueButton widget creates a button with the desired functionality. The button uses a GestureDetector to detect pan updates and ends, and it uses an AnimationController and SlideTransition to animate the text sliding inside the button. Once the animation completes, it displays the "Order" text using an AnimatedOpacity widget.

In the SlideToContinueButton widget, you can add a boolean _hideSlideText variable to keep track of whether the "slide to continue" text should be hidden or not. Once the slide animation completes, you can set the _hideSlideText variable to true and use it to conditionally show or hide the "slide to continue" text. Here's the updated code for the SlideToContinueButton widget.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SlideToContinueButton extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SlideToContinueButtonState createState() => _SlideToContinueButtonState();
}

class _SlideToContinueButtonState extends State<SlideToContinueButton>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController _controller;
  late Animation<Offset> _slideAnimation;
  bool _showOrderText = false;
  bool _hideSlideText = false;
  late Offset _dragStart;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
    );
    _slideAnimation = Tween<Offset>(
      begin: Offset.zero,
      end: Offset(1.0, 0.0),
    ).animate(_controller)
      ..addListener(() {
        setState(() {});
      })
      ..addStatusListener((status) {
        if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
          setState(() {
            _showOrderText = true;
            _hideSlideText = true;
          });
        }
      });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _onHorizontalDragUpdate(DragUpdateDetails details) {
    final dx = details.globalPosition.dx - _dragStart.dx;
    double slidePercent = dx / context.size!.width;
    slidePercent = slidePercent.clamp(0.0, 1.0);
    _controller.value = slidePercent;
  }

  void _onHorizontalDragEnd(DragEndDetails details) {
    if (_controller.value < 1.0) {
      _controller.reverse();
    } else {
      _controller.forward();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onHorizontalDragDown: (details) {
        _dragStart = details.globalPosition;
      },
      onHorizontalDragUpdate: _onHorizontalDragUpdate,
      onHorizontalDragEnd: _onHorizontalDragEnd,
      child: Container(
        height: 50.0,
        width: double.infinity,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.blue,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
        ),
        child: Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          children: [
            if (!_hideSlideText)
              ClipRect(
                child: SlideTransition(
                  position: _slideAnimation,
                  child: Text(
                    'slide to continue',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 18.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            AnimatedOpacity(
              opacity: _showOrderText ? 1.0 : 0.0,
              duration: Duration(milliseconds: 250),
              child: Text(
                'Order',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 18.0,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Now call it from anywhere

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:paint/SlideToContinueButton.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.amber
          ),
          child: SlideToContinueButton() ,
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: When i tap on it to slide it Then Text goes to end

Comment: I have updated the code for SlideToContinueButton class

Comment: When I swipe the text, it goes outside of the container. and also, after completing there is nothing any action perform. e.g., after swiping there should show a check icon and the text should hide.

Comment: `if (status == AnimationStatus.completed)` is not working

Comment: You can update the "Positioned" widget with "ClipRect" so that the text does not go outside. I don't understand what do u mean by check icon and the text should hide. From my end, I can see print function working when if (status == AnimationStatus.completed)

Comment: Thanks bro it worked. Can you tell me how can I slide it reverse also? I'll appreciate if you add the logic for reverse also. So that user can swipe on both directions.

Comment: Bro?? Kindly give me solution for this reverse swiping. when you'll online. thanks.